# How to define an AnimationSet in 3DS Max for the Direct3D Animation Controller

Tags: c++, animation, direct3d, 3dsmax

I'm building a Direct3D App using C++.
I managed to load a mesh hierarchy from an X file found in a tutorial which had different animations or tracks build into it. And just as the tutorial explained it worked fine.
I was able to switch between the animations in my App.

I had no luck with a custom made X file however.

The animation defined in 3DS Max and then converted to X plays fairly nice. But I don't seem to find a way to switch between animations. Actually I can't even define different Animation Sets in 3DS Max. Is it even possible to achieve this using 3DS Max?

I tried to find a programing solution to define the AnimationSets for the AnimationController using code but I can't seem to find any tutorial on this topic.

So if anyone knows of such tutorial or knows how to make Animations sets (tracks) in 3DS Max, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not state what exporter you use, so I dug up this one for you,

http://www.andytather.co.uk/Panda/directxmax.aspx

this plugin for 3dsmax supports animation naming named animation sets, amongst many other features.

Comment: I feel so stupid right now. I have been using the exact same exporter but I never paid any attention to the fact that it could name animation sets! For some reason I thought it was something 3DS Max should handle and I never went through the exporter's options.
Thanks a lot this one has been bugging me for quite some time!